# How to run two servers using one command line

Tags: shell, makefile

I would like to have one command line that runs both the grunt server and the elasticSearch server.

To run grunt server, I do:

```
python manage.py gruntserver
```

To run elastic search, I do:

```
elasticsearch --config=/usr/local/opt/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

I would like to simply run the following command and have both of the servers running:

```
make run
```

This is my attempt :

**makefile:**

```
run:
    echo "Setup..."
    elasticsearch --config=/usr/local/opt/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
    echo "Running gruntserver"
    ./manage.py gruntserver
```

The problem is when one server is run, it doesn't run the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

**makefile**

```
run:
    echo "Making files executable"
    chmod +x manage.py
    chmod +x ../scripts/setup.sh
    echo "Setup..."
    ../scripts/setup.sh & ./manage.py gruntserver
```

Where **setup.sh** has:

```
elasticsearch --config=/usr/local/opt/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
```